# How to fix ContextErrorException : Warning: Declaration

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm coping code from serveur in my local post, but I've got this error how can i fix this ?

```
ContextErrorException in Display.php line 0: 
Warning: Declaration of BWDisplay::setTemplate($template) should be compatible with FrontControllerCore::setTemplate($template, $params = Array, $locale = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7+ if you want to override or extend method you have to declare the same arguments(even if they have default values in the parent class method) and the same access level. In your code, it seems, that you extend `FrontController` class so you need to follow the rule and fill all arguments or at least set the same values as i the parent class `BWDisplay::setTemplate($template, array $params = array(), $locale = null)`

Answer (score 0):

try remplace :

```
BWDisplay::setTemplate($template);
```

By

```
$param = array();
$locale = 'NULL';
BWDisplay::setTemplate($template, $params, $locale);
```

regards